# How to reset the slide size in Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, slideshow

I am currently working on a slide master for powerpoint presentations, however it seems someone changed the slide size from the default value:

A 32px text is a lot "smaller" in the file I am working on vs. a new file I open:
[image: Text with 32px in current file]

[image: Text with 32px in a newly created file, appearing a lot bigger]

I would love to reset the slide size to what the powerpoint default is, however I am unsure how to do that and what the actual default size of Powerpoint is.

Answer (score 0):

The default size of the slide is changed in Design - Slide Size.
[image]

Comment: What Ceasar said.  But you'll want to click Custom Slide Size to make the change.  FWIW, it's possible (likely?) that someone created the original in some other program like Keynote which uses a much larger default slide size for some reason.

Comment: @steve-rindsberg but how do I know what the default size of powerpoint is when I click on "custom"? What values do I enter? Or maybe I misunderstood what you said

Comment: "Custom" lets you set the slide size to whatever you like (and will show you whatever oddball size it might currently be set to).  But per Ceasar's instructions, you can probably just set the slide to Standard or Widescreen.